# How to Reset Default Window Effects

Tags: 10.04, gnome, compiz

I was dumb and removed all the window effects under the compiz manager animation settings and I was wondering how to reset the window effects to what they were by default (using gnome).

**Update 1**

I think there's been some confusion regarding what, exactly, is being asked. I'm not asking how to switch effect levels. I'm asking how to bring back the default list of visual effects that are enabled once you choose "custom" in the effects preferences window. I removd all of the effects under the "open window" tab in "animations" and I'd like to know how to get them back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Visual Effects tab -> Normal
[image: Visual Effects]

Comment: So, what you're saying is that if I go from custom to normal and then back to custom, the default effects will be in place so I can edit them again?

Comment: I updated the question to better clarify what I'm asking

Answer (score 3):

In System -> Preferences -> Appearance, select the 'Visual Effects' tab.

Choose 'None' if you want the GNOME default (metacity) which doesn't have any of the compiz effects.

Choose 'Normal' if you want just a few effects.

Choose 'Extra' if you want lots of effects.

You can manually configure the effects by choosing 'Custom' (You need to install `simple-ccsm` or a similar tool for this option to be available).

[image: Visual Effects Preferences]

Comment: It should be noted that "Custom" is only available if simple-ccsm or another compiz configuration tool is installed.